# Injecting bash prompt to remote host via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, prompt

I have a fancy prompt working well on my local machine. However, I'm logging to multiple machines, on different accounts via ssh. I would love to have my prompt synchronized everywhere by ssh command itself.

Any idea how to get that? In many cases I'm accessing machines using root account and I can't change  permanently any settings there. I want the prompt synchronized.

In principle this is just setting variable PS1.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ssh -l root host -t "bash --rcfile /path/to/special/bashrc"
```

maybe `/path/to/special/bashrc` can be `/tmp/myrc` by example

Comment: I don't have my personal bashrc everywhere. I just need to set PS1 variable at start of the session.

Comment: To do this automagically, you can use a wrapper named ssh in your PATH before the ssh bin. This is AFAIK the only one solution if you don't want to just paste 'PS1=...' manually (it's another solution or a workaround...)